# Very many XElement instances in image processing

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, aforge

I have a big memory problem seems to be caused by many XElement instances.

What I have is a TabControl which shows an image in each Tab with a picture of cells (Imagine just a black picture with around 150 circles on it which are the cells).

[image: Here you can see how a part of the image looks after the detection]

I wrote an algorithm to detect those cells and get parameters like the diameter of them.

Here comes the problem: In idle the program uses around 200mb of memory. When I start the detection it goes up to 3.5GB. I used the In-Build memory profiler from visual studio and a 3rd party one to find the problem. The XElement instances start in idle at 3500 and after the detection they are at 45,000 instances and I can't tell why there are so many.

At the beginning of the detection I start the algorithm for every block of the image(the pictures are about 25000x25000 pixels so I have to devide them in blocks):

```
  while (startY + 1500 < sizeY)
        {
            while (startX + 1500 < sizeX)
            {
                Algorithm(startX, startY, 1500, 1500, count, result, selectedWorkspaceModel, parameterSet);
                count++;
                startX += 1500;
                last = false;
            }
            startX = 0;
            startY += 1500;
        }
```

The Algorithm Method:

```
 ObservableCollection<ImageObjectModel> ioms = selectedWorkspaceModel.ImageObjectModels;           
        result.Add(CellDetection.CellCategorizer(getBitmapSource(startX,startY,sizeX,sizeY), ImageDataAccessor.ImageDataSource.PixelSpacing.SpacingX, parameterSet)); //CellCategorizer actually does the detection of the cells. The getBitmapSource is an in-built method from the zeiss.micro library
        result.Last().BlockDescriptor = new BlockDescriptor(startX, startY, 1500, 1500); //position of block in image

        if (result[count] != null)
        {

            int cellResultLength = result[count].CellResults.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < cellResultLength; i++)  //All of the stuff in the loop is just to get the calculated cells in its own viewmodel to show a gallary of cells afterwars. This is not the problem
            {
                int startXCell = result[count].CellResults[i].CellsRectangle.X;

                int startYCell = result[count].CellResults[i].CellsRectangle.Y;
                int blockDX = result[count].BlockDescriptor.X;
                int blockDY = result[count].BlockDescriptor.Y;
                int rectangleWidth = result[count].CellResults[i].CellsRectangle.Width;
                int rectangleHeight = result[count].CellResults[i].CellsRectangle.Height;
                double cellDiameter = result[count].CellResults[i].CellDiameter;
                double feretMin = result[count].CellResults[i].FeretMinimum;
                double feretMax = result[count].CellResults[i].FeretMaximum;
                var state = result[count].CellResults[i].State;
                ImageBounds b = new ImageBounds(ImageBound);
                b.StartX = (startXCell + blockDX) - 10;
                b.StartY = (startYCell + blockDY) - 10;
                b.SizeX = rectangleWidth + 20;
                b.SizeY = rectangleHeight + 20;

                ImageObjectModel imageObjectModel = new ImageObjectModel(new ImageDataAccessor(selectedWorkspaceModel.ImageDataSource,b));

                if (state == CellResult.CellState.Match)
                {
                    imageObjectModel.State = ImageObjectModel.ClassificationState.Match;
                }
                else
                {
                    imageObjectModel.State = ImageObjectModel.ClassificationState.Mismatch;
                }

                imageObjectModel.StartX = (startXCell + blockDX);
                imageObjectModel.StartY = (startYCell + blockDY);

                imageObjectModel.CellDiameter = cellDiameter;
                imageObjectModel.FeretMax = feretMax;
                imageObjectModel.FeretMin = feretMin;

               ioms.Add(imageObjectModel); //Adds the iom to the list so that I can draw a rectangle around the cell after the detection
            }

        }
```

And finally the CellCategorization Method which uses the AForge library:

```
 if (_inputSource == null) throw new Exception();
        var inputBitmap = BitmapFromSource(_inputSource);
        if (!validatePixelFormat(inputBitmap))
        {
            inputBitmap = transformBitmap(inputBitmap);
        }
        BitmapData bitmapData = inputBitmap.LockBits(
     new Rectangle(0, 0, inputBitmap.Width, inputBitmap.Height),
     ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, inputBitmap.PixelFormat);

        filter2.CenterColor = new RGB(255, 255, 255);
        filter2.Radius = 430;
        filter2.ApplyInPlace(bitmapData);

        filter.CoupledSizeFiltering = true;
        filter.MinWidth = 10;
        filter.MinHeight = 10;
        filter.MaxHeight = Int32.MaxValue;
        filter.MaxWidth = Int32.MaxValue;
        filter.ApplyInPlace(bitmapData);

        bc.FilterBlobs = true;
        bc.MinWidth = 10;
        bc.MinHeight = 10;
        bc.MaxHeight = Int32.MaxValue;
        bc.MaxWidth = Int32.MaxValue;
        bc.CoupledSizeFiltering = false;
        bc.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.Size;
        bc.ProcessImage(bitmapData);
        Blob[] blobs = bc.GetObjectsInformation();
        BlockResult resultOfBlock = new BlockResult();
        inputBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        foreach (var rec in blobs)
        {
            var cuttedImage = inputBitmap.Clone(rec.Rectangle, inputBitmap.PixelFormat);//Need to get every cell seperated to perform further analysis
            double cellDiameter = Math.Sqrt(((rec.Area*(pixelSize*pixelSize)) / Math.PI)) * 2;
            cellDiameter *= 1000;
            var feretMax = calculateFeretMax( pixelSize,cuttedImage); //Similar things like here happen in this method so I don't want to spam you with extra code
            var feretMin = calculateFeretMin( pixelSize,cuttedImage);//Similar things like here happen in this method so I don't want to spam you with extra code
            CellResult result = new CellResult(Math.Round(cellDiameter,2),Math.Round( feretMax,2),Math.Round( feretMin,2));
            int countAccepted = 0;
            if ((feretMin > set.FeretMinimumMin && feretMin < set.FeretMinimumMax)) countAccepted++;
            if ((feretMax < set.FeretMaximumMax && feretMax > set.FeretMaximumMin)) countAccepted++;
            if ((cellDiameter > set.MinDiameter && cellDiameter < set.MaxDiameter)) countAccepted++;

            if(countAccepted>2) result.State = CellResult.CellState.Match;
            else if(countAccepted==2) result.State = CellResult.CellState.Unclassified;
            else result.State = CellResult.CellState.Mismatch;
            result.CellsRectangle = rec.Rectangle;
            resultOfBlock.CellResults.Add(result);

        }


        return resultOfBlock;
```

After the detection the memory stays at 3.5GB usage. But if i switch the Tab and the viewmodel of the shown TabItem changes, the memory usage is back at 200mb. Why are there so many instances of XElement and why do they stay in memory until I change the Tab and the ViewModel changes?

Comment: You haven't shown any code that refers to `XElement` as far as we can see, which makes it very hard to help you. I'm not surprised that loading a 25000x25000 image takes a lot of memory, but that wouldn't be in terms of `XElement`. Please provide a [mcve] which shows where you're actually using XML, and it'll be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: I find it somewhat odd that your question is about `XElement` instances causing memory problems while the code your provide is doing image recognition. How is XML involved in this process?

Comment: (It's possible that it's the library that's creating all the elements internally, of course - in which case the right course of action is to ask the creators of the library...)

Comment: Thanks to Jon Skeet. It was the getBitmapSource method from the Zeiss.micro library. I've tested the method before, but I made the mistake that I took the BitmapSource from the same part of the image in my test everytime. That seems to avoid the memory leak. I was now able to fix it and keep the application at around 300mb.